# Multiple Spinners setOnItemSelectedListener calling in OnCreate

Tags: android

How to use Multiple spinners in a single layout i.e., setting set On Item Selected Listener in on create

Comment: Did my answer take care of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You definitely should read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn what kind of questions to ask and how. If you want good answers and don't want your privileges to be revoked you need to be more specific about your questions and add relevant code and error messages showing that you have tried. But since you are new I'm going to give you this one. The easiest way to do this is attach the listener to each one in `onCreate()` after getting a reference to each `spinner` through your xml

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this;
```

then put the methods outside of `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int arg2,
        long arg3) 
{
    // do whatever you need here depending on what is selected
    // you can use a case statement and switch on the id to get the spinner (parent) or view

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

and add `Implements OnItemSelectedListener` in your `Activity` signature. Good luck and please ask more specific questions in the future and add code showing that you have made an attempt.